# finding the right regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

The Jmeter sampler returns a response in the following pattern:

> {"user":{"userId":1,"name":"Name1","email":"name1@email.com","role":"admin"},"type":"none"},
>   {"user":{"userId":2,"name":"User1","email":"user1@email.com","role":"user"},"type":"none"},{"user":{"userId":2,"name":"User2","email":"user2@email.com","role":"user"},"type":"none"}

The above tag repeats for multiple users

I need to replace the word 'none' (of tag 'type') with 'abc' for only those users whose email starts with 'user'.
After replacing, I need to send the entire replaced string as a POST request

I tried the following code in the Beanshell Postprocessor:

```
response = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); response = response.replaceAll("\"email\":\"user(\\d+)@email.com\",\"role\":\"user\"},\"type\":\"none\"}","\"email\":\"user\\d+@email.com\",\"role\":\"user\"},\"type\":\"abc\"}");
```

This replaces as expected except that the email is changed to userd+@email.com in all the matching patterns. I need to retain the email address as such. How do I solve this issue?
Thanks

Comment: You should prefer a json parser (http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/12/parsing-json-responses-with-jmeter/) over regex to retrieve the appropriate key's value and alter it since parser is a bit reliable approach, but you can do it with regex too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give a try with below one

```
response = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); response = response.replaceAll("\"email\":\"user(\\d+)@email.com\",\"role\":\"user\"},\"type\":\"none\"}","\"email\":\"user$1@email.com\",\"role\":\"user\"},\"type\":\"abc\"}");
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex uses positive lookbehind to make the assertion that the email should start with user :

```
(?<=\n.*user[^@]@.*)"type":"none"
```

And replace it with

```
"type":"abc"
```

What regex dialect/program language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Beanshell in Jmeter. The solution doesn't work unfortunately.  I get the following error: _jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``response = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); //response = response.replaceAll("\"e . . . '' Encountered "( \"(?<=\\n.*user[^@]@.*)\\\"type\\\":\\\"none\\\"\" , \"\\\"type\\\":\\\"abc\\\")\" ;" at line 4, column 31._

Comment: @V.Chandiran It could be that jmeter does not support variable width lookaround.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture what comes before the 'none' and use this capture in your replacement, like so

```
response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
response = response.replaceAll("(\"email\":\"user.+@email.com\",\"role\":\"user\"},\"type\":\")none\"","$1$abc\"");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the solution doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have now updated the answer to no longer capture the digits (this was in the original answer). I have no working jmeter setup so cannot test it.

Comment: No error is thrown. The replacement isn't happening. The original string is maintained as such